# How to use NSTimer UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nstimer

In my  app UITableVierwCell have an image(gradient cell image) and I want to show another image (gradient cell image) on same position in same cell at didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

I want to show when I select a cell then current cell image (gradient cell image) should be hide and another image (gradient cell image) should be display. I think this can be done by using NSTimer, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you use a NSTimer for this purpose. I will explain some idea in my mind.

Set the tag value for your first image view and place it on the cell. When user select the cell (ie in didSelectRowAtIndexPath)

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];

        UIView* imageCheckMark = [cell viewWithTag:kCellImageViewTag];
        if (imageCheckMark != nil) 
        {

            [imageCheckMark removeFromSuperview];
            [cell addSubview:secondImageView];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell addSubview:secondImageView];
        }

        [cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
```